# Best way to make text appear in equations

Tags: amsmath

I know there are a few questions on this, but I've found conflicting ideas and just wanted to know what people thought was best.

By inputting the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  Var(x)
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I want the Var bit to appear as normal text rather than as an italics style *Var*. I know I could use \mbox{} but was just wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: Welcome! Since `Var` looks like a math operator (function name), you should use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}` from `amsmath` to get the right spacing. Then you can use it just like `\sin`, etc: `\Var(x)`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  It's good that you want to know the 'right way' :)  Since it not only declares the *presentation* but also the *meaning*, `\DeclareMathOperator` is indeed that 'right way'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution of Paul Gessler is the best here:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
...
$\Var(x)$
```

If you really want to use text in math mode (and not a notation in roman font) you should use the `\text{...}` command from the `amsmath` package.

```
$V_{\text{atom}}$
```